# How to convert drupal php code into Core PHP code?

Tags: php, android, drupal

I have one web application using drupal.Now i am trying to make the same application in to android application. So I need to convert the drupal php files into core php file

Is it possible or can I use the same drupal php files into my android application

Please anyone help me in this because i have less idea in PHP and drupal

Comment: The best thing you could do is without learning drupal you try to understand the full functionality of the drupal application and build this with you normal php and android application. Else you have to learn a lot about drupal module, themes etc. You can take help or hire php guys for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if I understood you correctly, you are wanting to write up your drupal project so it can be accessed from mobile.  Let me assure you, you generally do not need to rewrite much to have drupal accessible on mobile. Of course this would not be a native app, but many themes have great built-in  mobile support. see [this list for a few examples].

Themes like [adaptive](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) and [corolla](http://drupal.org/project/corolla) makes it quite a breeze to push mobile content.

To recap, you would need to have:

1. Your site hosted on a webserver
2. Your drupal site fitted with a mobile / adaptive / responsive theme.

And you would be able to access your project from mobile.

Comment: I am making as a android application not a mobile website

Comment: kk, I don`t want to go off-topic, but how can you make a native android app in php? I thought android was java

Comment: I am not creating android application using PHP creating web service using that connecting android application and my remote database

Comment: Rather than presenting the site with different theming, you can go advanced by using Services module. You will need some learning in how API methods work. This lets you use native sliding and any native function in Android, keeping the web site's functionality,